# Reload custom scripts after component reload

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component and in the component blade file there is custom JS, and I have given a button for just a refresh of the component.

The problem is, when I click on the refresh button it does not execute custom scripts, but this custom script only works on the first page or first component load,

As soon as I click on `Refresh`, it does not work and comes to the default state.

How can I achieve scripts to execute when the component is loaded?

I tried with `@script`, `document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', () => {` but did not worked.

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light" wire:click="$refresh">Refresh</button>
</div>
<script>

    function scrollToRow(className) {
        var rowsToScroll = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        var tableContainer = document.querySelector('.table-container');
        if (rowsToScroll.length > 0 && tableContainer) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rowsToScroll.length; i++) {
                var element = rowsToScroll[i];
                var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
                var containerRect = tableContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
                var scrollableTop = elementRect.top - containerRect.top + tableContainer.scrollTop;
                var middle = scrollableTop - (containerRect.height / 2) + (elementRect.height / 2);
                tableContainer.scrollTo({
                    top: middle,
                    behavior: 'smooth' // Optionally, to scroll smoothly
                });
            }
        }
    }

...
//Some many JS ...

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add livewire listeners.
Add to your JS code

```
   document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', () => {
        @this.on('scrollToRow', (className) => {
            // rest of your code
        });
    });
```

And then, in your livewire component you need to add to refresh function

```
$this->dispatch('scrollToRow', 'yourClassNameParam');
```

Comment: This code needs to be run when the component is loading initially as well, right now with the above code, it runs when I click on the refresh button.

Comment: You can leave your function like you have it in your initial code, then on @this.on('scrollToRow') call that function.